# Max occurrences of consecutive character in a string.(Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How can I find out the max occurrences of consecutive character in a string and return the result as an array in sorted order.

Example:

```
    input = “abcccdddeee”
    output = [“c”,”d”,”e”]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is crude and likely can be improved, but you're basically looking at a simple state machine, where the current state is the previous character, and the next state is either a reset or an incrementation of a counter.

```
str = "abcccdddeee"

state = nil
current_count = 0
counts = {}
str.each_char do |char|
  if state == char
    current_count += 1
    counts[char] ||= 0
    counts[char] = current_count if current_count > counts[char]
  else
    current_count = 0
  end
  state = char
end

p counts.to_a.sort {|a, b| b[1] <=> a[1] }.map(&:first)
```

Since this only counts and stores counts when the current input causes the FSM to remain in the counting state, you don't get non-repeating characters in your output.

However, since this is Ruby, we can cheat and use regexes:

```
"abccdddeee".scan(/((.)\2{1,})/).map(&:first).sort_by(&:length).map {|s| s[0] }
```